# Firebase collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this database in firebase:
[image: firebase]

Then, I have this code in javascript:

```
firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('devices')
      .doc(device.id)
      .collection('pings')
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        doc.forEach(d => console.log(d))
      })
```

The problem is: my console log is showing this, instead of showing each object in the ping collection:
[image: consolelog]

Do any of you knows what's happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use data method on doc fetched from firestore

```
firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('devices')
      .doc(device.id)
      .collection('pings')
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        doc.docs.forEach(d => console.log(d.data())
      })
```

Comment: I did it. Hey, I'm trying to push the data into a array, like this: date.push(d.data().datetime), but when I try to console.log the date array, outside the firebase call, it seems null

Comment: what do you mean by it seems null can you post the log

Comment: It seems like I have to use a async await in some parte of my code, but I dont know how to use it. My code looks like the following:

Comment: inside the doc.forEach(d=> {date.push(d.data().datetime); console.log(date)}). Then, I close the firebase function and do a console.log(date). First, the console shows the date array empty, like this: [], and after, it shows the date array with the dates.

Comment: `firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('devices')
        .doc(device.id)
        .collection('pings')
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
          doc.forEach(d =>{
            
            date.push(d.data().datetime)
            console.log(date)
          } 
      )
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        console.log(date) `

Comment: okay so the call to firebase is asynchronous and while the call is being made to firebase to get your pings collection the rest of the code is executed hence it shows empty initially but when the call is made successfully and pings are fetched you get your dates

Comment: and how do I fix it? I mean, I know I have to use async await, but where do I put the async and where do I put the await?

Comment: You are using .then and .catch so you dont have to use async await, as for your code you can save your date in state once it is populated, so you can use       .get().then(doc => { doc.forEach(d => date.push(d.data().datetime))    setDates([...date]) }).catch(err => console.log(err))                                                                             here I am assuming that setDates is being used to set the date             as below                        const [dates, setDates] = useState([ ])  and you can use it anywhere using dates now